# How do i select only particular records from table when using dbml class?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, dynamic-data

In my project i'm using `dynamic data` controls to generate `lable` , `textbox` , `dropdownlist`

I'm binding all values using `.dbml` class as using `linq to sql`

now when i populate my dropdown with following code it is populated all the values which is there in table `Users` but i want to show only some values how can i achieve that?

code:

```
  partial class WorkFlow{}

    [DisplayName("Flow")]
    [DisplayColumn("FlowItem", "InitDate", true)]
    public class FlowMeta
    {
        [Display(Name = "Trade", Order = 1)]
        public WorkFlowItem WorkFlowItem { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Users", Order = 2)]
        public Users User { get; set; }
    }
```

Here it is populating all the records from `Users` table and dynamically bind it to dropdownlist how can I modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Function in this way in your Contorller:

```
 public void populatelistbox()
    {

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["user"].ToString());

        var enroll = from s in db.EnrollTrainee
                     join a in db.CreateUsers on s.TraineeID equals a.User_Userid
                     where s.TrainerID == id
                     select new { a.User_Userid, a.User_name };

        ViewBag.Enroll = new MultiSelectList(enroll, "User_Userid", "User_name");
    }
```

You need to Perform Some Conditions in your Lambda Operations according to your requirement.

After that you can Call this Function in this way:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        populatelistbox();
        return View();  
    }
```